# SQL query to calculate a BMI to 2 decimal places using height in inches in varchar and weight in pounds in varchar

Tags: sql, casting, calculated-columns

I'm trying to write an Amazon Redshift SQL query to calculate body mass index bmi using height in inches in varchar and weight in pounds in varchar to 2 decimal places. I have this which is not working:

```
SELECT ID,
       CAST(height_in AS decimal),
       CAST(weight_lbs AS decimal),
       CAST(CAST(weight_lbs AS decimal(4, 2))/ (CAST(height_in AS decimal(4, 2)) * CAST(height_in AS decimal(4, 2))) * 703 AS decimal(4, 2)) AS calc_bmi
FROM table
WHERE
 table.ID IN ('a', 'b');
```

Thank you!

Comment: `decimal(6,2)`might do the trick. Any lbs of above 100 gets trimmed to 99,99 when yout use `decimal(4,2)`

Comment: I ended up getting this. I think it may be an issue with the parentheses placements?  [XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid input syntax for type numeric Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid input syntax for type numeric code: 8 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with `decimal(6,2)` as I already stated in the comment. Plus your query missed one pair parentheses.

```
(weight / (height * height)) * 703
```

Instead of:

```
weight / (height * height) * 703
```

Since the latter will first multiply (height<sup>2</sup> * 703), which is not what you want.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT ID,
        CAST(height_in AS decimal),
        CAST(weight_lbs AS decimal),
        CAST((CAST(weight_lbs AS decimal(6, 2))/ (CAST(height_in AS decimal(6, 2)) * CAST(height_in AS decimal(6, 2)))) * 703 AS decimal(6, 2)) AS calc_bmi
FROM table
WHERE
table.ID IN ('a', 'b');
```

EDIT: it is vital that with these queries your database actually contains values for `height_in` and `weight_lbs`, otherwise the `CAST` operations will trow errors.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I had changed everything to decimal(6,2) earlier and ran your code now but still get the same error.

Comment: XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid input syntax for type numeric Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid input syntax for type numeric code: 8 ...

Comment: Check that the fields in the database are not empty. Also check for characters that are not numeric. Start with a database with just one row and don't have an characters other than numbers and "." in them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I realized that some of the duplicate fields in my database were indeed empty and once I eliminated them the code ran error-free. I am a newbie to coding. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer.